# Access remote database failed,"(1045,Access denied for user......)"

Tags: python, database, mysql-python

local machine environment:

- centos 6.7
- python 2.7.10
- Flask-MySQLdb 0.2.0
- local ip: 112.25.76.72
- remote ip: 221.228.203.203

Both of the code run on local Machine;

when I access the remote database in local python command line environment like this:

```
>>>import MySQLdb
>>>conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="221.228.203.203",user="test_user",passwd="test_passwd",db="test_db",charset="utf-8")
```

it access successfully,but when I write these code into a python script login.py:

```
import MySQLdb

conn = None

try:
    conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="221.228.203.203",user="test_user",passwd="test_passwd",db="test_db",charset="utf-8")
    cur = conn.cursor()

except Exception,e:
    print e

finally:
    if conn:
        conn.close()
```

then execute "python login.py" in the terminal,it access failed,the error info is :

`(1045, "Access denied for user 'test_user'@'112.25.76.72' (using password: YES)")`

Why? Their python environment is the same.

if you can solve it,please help me.

Comment: where did u run the first code? from localhost? May be the user test_user can only be logined from localhost. U should check the configurations of your database or user. The code is right.   "Access denied for user 'test_user'@'112.25.76.72' show the ip (112.25.76.72) of the machine, where u run the second code

Comment: Yes,both of the code run in local machine and ip is "112.75.76.72". And which configuration file should I check???

Answer (score 0):

You should check the configurations of your user in the database server. It will be stored in database mysql.
You can get the list of users with:

```
SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user;
```

You shouldn't delete the user test_user@localhost. You can try to execute it on your database server

```
CREATE USER 'test_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'test_passwd'
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'test_user'@'%'  WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'test_user'@'localhost'  WITH GRANT OPTION;
```